# jquery filter return all match remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

If you click on the selected checkboxes, the problem is encountered while writing code that `removes()` the input `val` value that matches the `val` value in the checkbox, using each while it is being deleted.

**Problem**
When there are two or more checked checkboxes, only the first one is deleted even if the value of `val` is the same.

```
onlyremove.click(function () {
    var chk = $("input[name='cbx']:checked").length;
    $("input[name='cbx']:checked").each(function() {
        pickbtn.find('.ordering').filter(function () {
            return $("input[name='cbx']:checked").val() && $(this).find('.number').val() == $("input[name='cbx']:checked").val();
        }).text('rldd'),alert('123123'), --num;
    });
});
```

Comment: share your code with working snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Click the button ` <> ` at the top of your post contents or `ctrl + M`. Then enter your javascript, html and css in the relevant boxes. We will be able to help you then.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf51mszm/2/